# Url in django template contains domain

Tags: python, django

Trying to insert `{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}` in an email as a link, but the result is something as `http://domain//domain.localhost:8000/reset_password/uidb64/token` which is an invalid link. The desired url would be `http://domain/reset_password/uidb64/token`.

I'm using get_current_site(request).domain and I pass protocol inside context.

When only outputting the `{% url ... %}` block, it begins with `//domain.localhost:8000/reset...`, which also occurs when trying with different url endpoints. I believe the whole `//domain.localhost:8000` shouldn't be there.

I have a few django apps inside a directory called apps and the core project, as:

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── players
│   ├── website
│   ├── registration
│   └── games
└── core
```

core.urls.py has

```
url(r'^players/', include('apps.players.urls')),
```

and in apps.players.urls.py

```
url(r'^change_password/?$', change_password, name='change_password'),
url(r'^reset_password/?$', password_reset, name='password_reset'),
url(r'^reset_password/(?P<uidb64>[^/]+)/(?P<token>.+)/?$', password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^reset_password/done/?$', password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
url(r'^reset_password/complete/?$', password_reset_complete, name='password_reset_complete'),
url(r'^resend_activation_email/(?P<username>.+)/?$', resend_activation_email, name='resend_activation_email'),
```

and the corresponding view:

```
password_reset = PasswordResetView.as_view(html_email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html')
```

Comment: Can you please share your `urls.py` and more of the code? E.g. where and how do you set `protocol` and `domain`? The `url` built-in will return the absolute path reference, see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url): "Returns an absolute path reference (a URL without the domain name) matching a given view and optional parameters."

Comment: Specify the desired url.

Answer (score 0):

Can You please specify what are you sending in `domain, protocol` variables?
Also if you are send it from views, then you can use `request.get_host()` To get the current host. And `request.scheme` To get current protocol.